# getting rid of lower bar in colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I want to use colorbox to display a form. The form will have two buttons, one for submitting the form and one for dismissing the window created by colorbox.

I have been following the [examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/), particularly the so called *Outside HTML (Ajax)*. It works, but I am trying not to show the close button and to hidden also the whole bar that colorbox uses to display the title and other button for galleries.

If I set `closeButton:false`, the close button is not shown but I still have some white space at the bottom that I'd like to remove.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Does setting `title` to false help?

Comment: post some code so that we can get it out solved??